# The use of: "Wanted" vs "Would Want" in sentences

Tags: meaning, informal-language

What is the difference between "wanted" and "would want"?

"Wanted" would be more informal or it has other meaning? I see some texts or even music,

“*What I wanted  to  be..*” - John Lennon

In sentence: "*I wanted to eat a chocolate, please*"

The questions is: I SEE the same meaning

Comment: "I wanted a chocolate, please" is ungrammatical. It should be: 8I want a chocolate, please.*

Answer (score 2):

This is a tense difference

**Past tense** - previously I wanted to be something. You may or may not still want to be that thing

> **Wanted**
>
> *something* is what I wanted to be
>
> When I was a child, I wanted to be an astronaut

**Future tense** (typically hypothetical) - in a certain circumstance, this is what you would like.

> **Would want**
>
> I would want *something*
>
> If I was hungry, I would want some soup

Or **Future tense** but this time not hypothetical. This is what you are going to want, regardless of circumstance

> **Will want**
>
> *In future* I will want *something*
>
> Later tonight I will want to sit down and watch a film

And the one you didn't include **Present tense**. Right now, you want this.

> **Want**
>
> I want *something*
>
> I want a chocolate

Although remember that "want" is referring to the future. So even in the present tense you're talking about what you would like to happen either in the immediate or distant future.